# Общество программистов

Tags: обсуждение

Поделитесь опытом, как вы пришли к тому, кто вы есть. Ну не сразу же рождаются с клавиатурой в руках. Расскажите как поняли, что можете называть себя `программистом`, ну что вот вы уже опытный и уверенны, что `пишете хорошо свой код`.
Ведь программисты могут передать свои знания, поделиться `лайфХаками`с новичками, и тд. Сама имею несколько образований и основной диплом в сфере информатики `Инженер-Программист` бакалавра. Дело тут ведь не в образовании...Иногда говорят, пиши код, как можно больше пиши, ну пишу. А как и где опыта набраться? Где и с кем посоветоваться и спросить корректировки работ?

Comment: если по миру прям - то явно не на ruSO. Если хотя бы с русскоговорящими - telegram,  vk.   Если  с зарубежными.... ну нельзя тут писать такое (ссылки на эти ресурсы) в наше время..... можно поискать что-то подобие ТГ и там чатиться

Comment: @Dev18 задайте этот вопрос в чате: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Comment: @МихаилРебров а к какой именно теме вы относите это ```сквери-плюгины; бинайс; драма; киски; модераторский-произвол; филанзий; или может быть нытье )))``` ? ‍️

Comment: @Dev18 не понял вопроса.

Comment: @МихаилРебров не поняла комментария.

Comment: @Dev18, это с тех времен, когда люди там еще шутили по разным поводам, связанным с текущей жизнью (да, когда-то он был еще живой) сайта

Comment: @avp здесь как я успела заметить направо и налево ```...могут на минусЪ послать```  при слишком активном житиЕ, а рыба как известно гниет с головы //вот он и не успевает ПЕРЕоживиться сайт то //,,,сидят грустные на минусах и в отшельниках 

Comment: Пугают минусы на вопросе? Посмотрите [сюда](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388702/339911) (+11/-33) и не расстраивайтесь. Минусы на Мете репутацию на основном сайте не испортят. Хотя что считать репутацией - это вопрос. Менять кардинально вопрос, особенно который уже получил ответ не принято. Поэтому я откатил версию до изменения сути

Comment: Меня мало что пугает в жизни, но порой удивляет, например ваши нелогичные правки...

Comment: О каких правка речь, давайте чуть подробнее?

Comment: Ответ он получил на сааааамую первую версию, а вы откатили на мою биографию

Comment: Новые правила прям на ходу придумываете, ответ год назад дан был....я после этого ещё пару тройку раз меняла вопрос)))и ничего тихо все было

Comment: @αλεχολυτ  Просьба к вам, удалите этот вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: Сама шишки набив научусь сама себе код ревью подправлю

Comment: Минусов (как и плюсов) больше не будет. Обошлось без удаления.

Answer (score 6):

У нас уже есть [чаты](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com). Можете переходить и общаться :)

Comment: Ну как общаться.....смотреть на сообщения ботов разве что)) ....... сейчас в чатах почти никого нет. Даже в пустыне больше живности...... А вот года 4 назад (до некоторых событий) было прям людно, было активно, мы писали, общались, шутили.....Сообщения рекой текли порой.......Теперь....ну не то, чтобы трава раньше была зеленее, но теперь явно никого почти там нет.......проще пойти в какой-нибудь ТГ канал по IT. Их (каналов) там (в ТГ) много..

Comment: @АлексейШиманский На счёт частого общения ничего не могу сказать, но в целом не согласен. Людей стало меньше в чатах? Может быть, я не застал время, когда там было много. Но это не значит что там не с кем общаться, я туда пишу иногда, видел как другие пишут, бывают небольшие разговоры. Из последних более менее продолжительных обсуждений было между мной, avp и Kromster, спорили на счёт закрытия вопросов. В чате политота постоянно что-то обсуждают, в чате мета вопросов мы постоянно играем в пинг понг) Так что если прям сильно хочется общаться то можно) А что за "до некоторых событий"?

Comment: В пинг-понг играться не равно общаться)) Политота - опять же не про IT. И грязь обсуждать - ну такое.  ......редкие обсуждения других вопросов - раз в пятилетку. ...Ну и как бэ всё

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну я и не говорил что пинг-понг - это общаться, просто привёл как пример развлечения)) Политота - не ИТ, ну тут не могу спорить, но зато чат жив)) Но в обычном чате, время от времени идут обсуждения, правда короткие, но зато никто никого не игнорит почти)) А что за события 4-х летней давности, что после этого чаты опустели?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский основной чат всегда +/- активен. Это в мета-вопросах пинг-понг и малочисленные фразы о мета-вопросах.

Comment: В принципе в чатах есть жизнь. Только везде разная:  в основном чате постоянная; в политоте - специфичные темы для обсуждения; в мета-вопросах - пинг-понг; В цитатном чате - цитаты и шутки; чат "c/c++" тоже вроде живёт своей жизнью.

Comment: @Зонтик ой да лааааадно. два сообщения в месяц называть "активным". Либо у вас требования к активности такие маленькие... Сейчас вот обсуждения модеров закончатся и опять будет только перекатиполе летать..и один модер сидеть круглосуточно в чате. Раньше там по 15 человек зависало и каждый день,  тройку сотен сообщений писали. Было действительно живо. А смотреть на сообщения Feeds и SmokeDetector и говорить что это "есть жизнь", ну такое

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да нет, даже в основном чате бывает в день по 20 сообщений, не обязательно про выборы.

Comment: @Зонтик вот я и говорю, у вас требования к "активности" явно очень маленькие. 20 сообщений в день на фоне трёхсот - явно говорит о том, что жизнь там НЕ активная. Да и сами подумайте, при наличии большого количества людей - 20 сообщений это норма? Если 20 человек скажут привет. Это такое себе. Даже мы сейчас вдвоём ужЕ 4 сообщения напишем.....а 20...ну крч, фигня это...... и нет...там нет столько сообщений. в основном пустота.. достаточно всю историю глянуть