# Улучшение окна создания вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы

Основной тезис, который я хочу донести:

При создании вопроса фокус на окошке с Markdown, поэтому мало кто отведет глаза направо чтобы почитать, потому что оно сливается с общим фоном и вообще никак не выделяется. Доказательство - постоянное всплывание вопросов с ужасным оформлением, с телом вопроса который оказался в заголовке и прочее.

Что было бы неплохо изменить:

1. Сделать боксы с шагами, как сделать черновик и больше полезных ссылок сделать выделяющимися.
2. Изменить текст не "черновик", а просто 3 пункта как задать вопрос [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (сделать выдержку).
3. Полезные ссылки можно перенести вместо визуального мусора в хидере вопроса, который существует "лишь бы заполнить страничку", сделать выделяющимися. Хотя на момент написания вопроса я начал сомневаться в переносе.

МВП реализация которую я вижу:

1. Сделать более выделяющимися боксы 1 и 2 (см. скриншот).
2. Бокс "полезные ссылки" раскрыть за юзера.
3. В боксе 1 убрать "Сообщество здесь, чтобы помочь вам..."

Ну и да, причина почему этот вопрос возник: я за 2.5 года задавания вопросов впервые увидел эти боксы совсем недавно просто потому, что мозг фильтрует всякие тусклые невыделяющиеся баннеры. Тем более такая важная штука "как задать качественный вопрос" вообще оказывается **СКРЫТА!** И чтобы узнать как задать вопрос надо мало того что отвлечься от написания и посмотреть направо, так еще и раскрыть окошко на 2 боксе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: или, если мы зависим от EnSo, просто взять их новый механизм(потому как раньше было как сейчас у нас). Если кто задавал там вопрос последние три месяца, могут знать как работает там. там не пройдя первый шаг, второй невозможно заполнить. А три шага что-то типа (я точно не помню): 1. что вы пытаетесь сделать 2. что вы сделали и пробовали, опишите ваши действия 3. приложите код с объяснением

Comment: и еще последний этап, там фокусируется, на предложенных ссылках, 'ознакомтесь может кто то уже задал похожий вопрос'...

Comment: *"фокус на окошке с markdown, поэтому мало кто отведет глаза направо чтобы почитать.....Доказательство - постоянное всплывание вопросов с ужасным оформлением"*  --- дело не в фокусах и не в оформлении, а, банально, в людях и их головах.

Comment: Можно хоть прожекторами подсветить якобы нужные разделы, всё равно индивидуумы с линейным зрением просто шмякают "задать вопрос" -> впихнуть текст -> "опубликовать" -> убежал по своим делам радостный и довольный

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тогда 4 подтверждения "я прочитал" сделать, подтвердил 1 раз -> потом еще один и так 4 раза )))

Comment: @Aarnihauta люди просто 4 раза шмякнут "да"/"ок" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  Им не интересно что там за текст будет написан.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тогда надо давить на жалость, написать "вы прочитали?", "вы точно прочитали?", "мы очень надеемся на вас! прочитайте! :(" и на каждом этапе прикреплять фото грустного котёнка.

Comment: @Aarnihauta нее, это не поможет. Люди, которые задались целью вкинуть на стек низкокачественный вопрос, абсолютно безжалостны: их не остановят ни котята, ни собачки, ни что-либо ещё. Ведь зачастую они после этого даже на сайт никогда больше не заходят))

Comment: @Byb да ладно, эти юзеры просто не знают о том, что тут надо как-то что-то оформлять. Обычно представление что so это сайт помогалка где за тебя решат любую проблему

Comment: @Byb таких злостных участников гораздо меньше, чем тех, кто думает, что ruSO - форум.

Comment: @Aarnihauta *"просто не знают о том, что тут надо как-то что-то оформлять"* --- о, камон, чел, ты серьёзно в это веришь? Я, уже лет 20 как, приходя на любой ресурс, ищу инструменты для адекватного форматирования текста. И форматтеры есть на **любом** ресурсе и форуме (как любят пришедшие писать). Любая textarea для комментов имеет кнопки форматирования. Я всегда стремлюсь сделать так чтобы мой текст не выглядел сплошным нечитаемым месивом. И те, кому не всё равно, делают точно так же.... А вот кому, извините, насрать, те просто вкидывают и убегают. Повторюсь: **дело в головах**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, во всём виноват Чубайс)

Comment: @Aarnihauta и кстати, при регистрации всегда человеку показывается ТУР : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour  в котором вкратце описывается что тут такое, для чего...В конце ссылка на справочный центр, в котором можно почитать что тут как оформлять и т.д.... Так что приходящий, считается, уже должен был с этим ознакомиться по пути....Однако, мы-то понимаем, что все просто скипают к "развязке". Точно так же никто никогда не читает лицензионных соглашений, просто дайте, наконец, попользоваться.... Тут так же)) Как в Омерике говорят: cut to the chase

Comment: На мой взгляд, те, кто хотят оформить свой вопрос/ответ, они его оформляют и визуальные/дизайнерские особенности не препятствуют этому. В интерфейсе SO есть более необходимые вещи, до которых уже n...цать лет не доходят руки разработчиков (сворачивающийся код, поддержка Java/C#/etc. в сниппетах кода, мобильное приложение, etc.).

Comment: @XelaNimed так этот вопрос и был создан отсюда https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13161/264178, где и была рекомендация создать свой вопрос по тому, что если считаете "более важным" , есть некая лесенка иерархий важностей важного...#идлявсехонапоходуразная

Answer (score 5):

Указанные изменения не вносят однозначных улучшений, то есть вместе с улучшениями они вносят и ухудшения.

Например, добавление веса сайдбару ещё больше перегрузит и без того перегруженную страницу. Я бы вообще весь сайдбар и прочее лишнее убрал и добавил бы странице больше интерактива. Чем меньше букв в общей массе, тем больший вес у оставшихся букв.

Важную информацию про задавание качественных вопросов никто читать не будет вообще независимо от того, насколько ярко она будет бросаться в лицо участникам.

Вставляя препятствия на стадии создания вопроса участнику, можно добиться только того, что **вопрос вообще не будет задан**. Как по мне, пусть лучше опытные участники с правами на редактирование помогают с оформлением вопросов, чем если этих вопросов не станет вообще.

Слабо оформленные вопросы для нас не проблема, а рутина. Так устроен StackOverflow, во всяком случае пока так.

Comment: А почему не будут читать? Это очередная мантра, которую повторяют, но никак не обосновывают. От программистов ожидается, что они читают какую-то информацию об используемых инструментах и делают по ней. Нельзя даже сверстать сайт-визитку, не прочитав какой-нибудь "HTML для чайников". Те, кто ничего не читают, это кто? Студенты-двоечники, которые не планируют работать по специальности?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight пользователи читают только то что им надо. Это популярная UX-проблема, которую до конца по сегодняшний день никто на планете не решил. Это не мантра, это факт уровня "трава зелёная". Пользователь идёт читать соглашение ровно в тот момент, когда появляется для него выгода в его прочтении, и ни минутой раньше. Я не беру в расчёт редкие исключения из этой закономерности. Улучшить можно что угодно, исправить - нет.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight "*Нельзя даже сверстать сайт-визитку, не прочитав какой-нибудь "HTML для чайников"*" --- забавно, но 90% вопросов на текущем ресурсе в стиле "как вставить переменную в строку" или "почему моё условие в виде if ($test = 1 || 2 || 4 || 5)  не работает", хотя всё это написано в любой книжке "для чайников".....Мной лично замечено, что люди сюда приходят не читая вообще ни одной книги для новичков. Просто посмотрев пару видосиков на ютубе...... Так что вот эти вот самые и не смотрят никуда....и, что самое ужасное, как раз такие и **собираются работать в it**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так и есть. Программировать стало "проще, чем завтрак приготовить".

Comment: _Чем меньше букв в общей массе, тем больший вес у оставшихся букв._ ===>  идеально сказано, именно идея что я и несла. Ведь на en so они убрали весь 'шум' и сделали уютную комнату вопроса. У них получилось 'исправить' хоть и не на сто процентов но на много. Они думают порой достаточно креативно, что позволяет 'гипнотизировать' и менять общество. У нас есть черта 'нести' общество на плечах. Мы выдержим рутину, мы сильные...

Comment: ... Самое парадаксальное в этом, что мы несём несём несём, а потом в один момент можем просто сбросить.... И сказать я устал я ухожу.... Так лучше все таки изменить, чтоб они сами шли, чем даже не пытаться...

Comment: Страх, что не придут, равносилен страху когда его сбросят, а он даже не поймёт зачем. На сайте есть очень много людей, которые изменились и стали лучше задавать вопросы. Люди могут меняться становится лучше. Среди молодых программистов есть грамотные ровно столько же сколько в 90-00х глуповатых. Дедушкины фразы по типу, а раньше было лучше доказывают только лишь то, что мы себя забываем и слишком идеализируем. Есть простой ответ почему есть критика этому вопросу и это факт, ответ в том что руки у нас не достанут ничего менять тут вот и мы и говорим что это бяка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы преувеличиваете. По мне так вопросов от совсем чайников где-то 10% (по крайней мере, по меткам, в которых я обитаю).

Comment: @Зонтик ну-да ну-да.... а [основной чат всегда +/- активен, наполнен жизнью и каждый день есть с кем пообщаться](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12083/#comment54516_12085)... ага....пора перестать жить в иллюзии

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а почему вы не проголосовали "за" этот ответ?

Comment: @Dev18 Во-первых: текущий ответ никоим образом ни на что не влияет: ни на дизайн, ни на судьбу ruSO в целом.....Во-вторых: ответ может частично совпадать с мнением человека.....В-третьих: никто (в т.ч. и я)  **не обязан** голосовать за всё, что попадается на пути. Делать имитацию полезной активности - это, вон, к Зонтику.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский буквально на днях в рекомендациях возле одного вопроса всплыла ваша "активность" https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3983/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82 просто легко говорится это не ко мне, вон зонтик "староста" класса, а в 2016 году вы тоже самое делали. Человек проходит один и тот же путь, кто то раньше кто то позже.... (Если кто то ходит на ногах смеяться над младенцом странно... )

Comment: Вы тут все знаете, давно на сайте, и ведёте себя немного как старший брат у которого отняли его кубики.... И ваши вопросы минусовали и вы "ныли" на месте и в чатах, сейчас вы заработали карму и репутацию и занижаете труд новичков. Вы очень даже хороший человек, просто под разным ракурсом вы пытаетесь разжечь дровами спор, зачем? Ну да ладно, я не буду продолжать тут полемику, все равно это лишь разожгет ваш потенциал спора и сравнений (помидор огурец, итп) про голосование я спросила потому что спорить про то что не интересно, но при этом не поддерживать то под чем спор

Comment: (ок, раз "частично" согласны... Хотя тут либо белое либо чёрное).....

Comment: Если занижать других, себя этим не поднять.... Это я так, мысли вслух. Берегите друг друга, мы пока еще люди. Пока ещё.... Я учусь у каждого. Прислушиваюсь если разумное замечание и признаю если сказала глупость. Это тоже нужно уметь. Кстати после вашего совета в одних из комментов нашла себе педагога информатики. Это я не к вам для лести, а чтоб показать что углы разные и этот вопрос вы сами в душе поддерживаете, но вступаете в спор. Программисты не те.... Никто не читает...... Все плохо, а что хорошо?

Comment: Я знаете сколько книг прочла по информатике.... Но не понимаю пока на примере не объяснят.... Дело же не в книгах чтоб классифтцировать программистов...... Все это полемика.... Я молчу!!! Но вы всегда и везде разжигаете просто спор на все "бяка" говоря.... Хоть обосновывайте иногда негодование. А не просто фууу, тупыыыые, фууууу не читают..... Мы попробовали??????? НЕТ!!! Так как мы можем знать как будет.....

Answer (score 2):

Если мне память не изменяет, то тут уже несколько раз поднимался подобный вопрос

Мне больше всего понравился вариант - создать пространство куда сначала попадут вопросы, перед тем как его увидит масса

Но естественно это будет бить по скорости ответа на вопрос. Я бы предложил немного улучшенный вариант этого механизма:

1. Вопрос задан участником с репутацией больше 500 (можно и другое число)?
2. Если да, то сразу опубликовать вопрос
3. Если нет, то вопрос идёт на проверку. Далее отсчитывается таймер, например на 24ч (можно и другое число) после которого, если вопрос не был проверен, то он автоматом попадает в общий доступ

Мне кажется, что если развивать этот вариант, то можно придумать что-то более лучшее, чем просто подсказки, которые большинство игнорируют

Comment: Так ведь есть очередь "первые вопросы"... Вроде все и так по этой схеме работает.

Comment: @Глеб Справедливо, но там ответ сразу видит массы, потому кто-то может и ответить, а тогда автор не станет что-то менять т.к. уже получил ответ. Много кто сюда заходит 1 раз в жизни чтобы спросить и испариться)

Comment: А-а... Да, понял, разумно. Только, боюсь, никто не будет заморачиваться с созданием новой очереди... А так идея хорошая.

Comment: Про попадание вопросов в временное хранилищу плохая идея. Ждать 24 часа только для того, чтобы вопрос был ПРОСТО ОПУБЛИКОВАН не очень приятно. Да даже 1 час. И конечно, главное: у нас в среднем за год вопросов **100** в день (иногда количество опускается до 80, иногда поднимается до 130). Подумайте, какой процент вопросов будет реально проверен, а у какого процента **просто задержится публикация**.

Comment: @Зонтик В этом и заключается суть метода, который не даёт публиковать шлак сразу. Естественно это будет бить по скорости. Я же говорю, что этот метод нужно просто развить. Например можно добавить галку, что пользователь может быть заблокирован, если вопрос не следует рекомендациям и тогда вопрос отобразится сразу. Это не идеальное решение, но я думаю хорошая точка старта. Возможно можно будет потом прикрутить ИИ, который будет решать пропускать вопрос или стоит отправить нам на проверку и тогда будут 2 дополнительные очереди))))))))) Идея +- реализована на https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: И потом, я просто сказал, что эта идея просто больше всех остальных мне тогда понравилась, и я просто чутка его смягчил. Я даже не сомневаюсь что есть более лучшие решения)

Comment: Golf.SE - это не сайт вопросов и ответов. Это сайт для соревнований. К ним требования другие. Нет необходимости их запускать сразу. А у вопросов есть: не будет никто задавать вопросы на ruSO, если для публикации вопроса нужно будет ждать сутки. Ну, может, и будет, но тогда численность вопросов будет ничтожно мала.

Comment: @Зонтик Почему вы из контекста вырываете суть? Я разве где-то сказал что у нас одинаковые требования? Я просто сказал, что похожая идея уже реализована и там при желании можно сразу опубликовать ответ. По-моему идея с отдельным местом для первых вопросов даже на enSO предлагалась, не знаю уже чем закончилось

Comment: @EzioMercer это я про то, что на гольфе.SE эта идея является реализуемой. На ruSO нет.

Comment: На мой взгляд плохая идея. 1. Так как 100% вопросов проверить можно будет не всегда, то это не исключит попадания "шлака" в публикации. 2. Задержка в публикации хорошо оформленных вопросов исключит/отторгнет нормальных пользователей.

Comment: @XelaNimed Понятно, что и высокорепые могут шлак постить, это просто усложняет немного жизнь новичкам, чтобы заставить их следовать правилам. По опыту, люди, которые сюда зашли впервые крайне редко пишут хорошо оформленный вопрос. И если пользователь нормальный, то он поймёт почему для новичков есть такое правило) Например при публикации игр, перед тем как попасть на маркет они проходят тщательную проерку, но никого это не отталкивает. Опять же это просто идея, возможно на его основе кто-то предложит в разы лучше варинат, просто этот вопрос уже не раз поднимался и мне понравился этот вариант